Get only one key from JSON array and by default empty values for array values
I have a JSON input as below :
{
  "data": [
    {
      "accessCriterias": [
        {
          "name": "level1",
          "id": "1234"
        }
      ],
      "userRoleGroups": [
        {
          "name": "all_grp",
          "id": "456"
        },
        {
          "name": "read_only_grp",
          "id": "234"
        }
      ],
      "firstName": "first_name_1"
    },
    {
      "accessCriterias": [],
      "userRoleGroups": [],
      "firstName": "first_name_2"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_3"
    }
  ],
  "next": true
}

I want below output:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_1",
      "userRoleGroups": [
        {
          "name": "all_grp",
          "id": "456"
        },
        {
          "name": "read_only_grp",
          "id": "234"
        }
      ],
      "accessCriterias": [
        {
          "name": "level1",
          "id": "1234"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_2",
      "userRoleGroups": [],
      "accessCriterias": []
    },
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_3",
      "userRoleGroups": [],
      "accessCriterias": []
    }
  ],
  "next": true,
  "nextOffset": 50
}

Output format:

If userRoleGroups and accessCriterias fields values are blank (i.e. empty array) (like in 2nd JSON object in input) OR if these two fields are not present itself (like in 3rd JSON object in input), then in the output userRoleGroups and accessCriterias fields value should come as empty array i.e. [].
For userRoleGroups and accessCriterias only 'name' should come in output and not 'id'

I tried below JOLT and I am able to achieve the 1st point of Output format but not able to achieve the 2nd point of Output format. I don't want 'id' from the output.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "userRoleGroups": [],
          "accessCriterias": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "size_userRoleGroups": "=size(@(1,userRoleGroups))",
          "size_accessCriterias": "=size(@(1,accessCriterias))"
        }
      }
    }
},
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "firstName": "data[&1].firstName",
          "size_userRoleGroups": {
            "*": {
              "@2,userRoleGroups": "data[&3].userRoleGroups"
            }
          },
          "size_accessCriterias": {
            "*": {
              "@2,accessCriterias": "data[&3].accessCriterias"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "next": "next"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "nextOffset": 50
    }
  }
]

Output I get from using above JOLT:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_1",
      "userRoleGroups": [
        {
          "name": "all_grp",
          "id": "456"
        },
        {
          "name": "read_only_grp",
          "id": "234"
        }
      ],
      "accessCriterias": [
        {
          "name": "level1",
          "id": "1234"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_2",
      "userRoleGroups": [],
      "accessCriterias": []
    },
    {
      "firstName": "first_name_3",
      "userRoleGroups": [],
      "accessCriterias": []
    }
  ],
  "next": true,
  "nextOffset": 50
}


I believe it's what you need.
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "nextOffset": 50,
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "userRoleGroups|accessCriterias": []
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "userRoleGroups|accessCriterias": { "*": { "id": "" } }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

